# Amazon Web Services Solution won't build in Release mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to build the solution with AWSSDK for .net. When I use Debug mode, it works properly but when I try to build solution in Release mode, it throws error saying (just to clarify, I'm using visual studio Express 2013 for Desktop):

**The type or namespace name "Amazon" could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

I'm also getting this Warning Message: **Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "AWSSDK". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.**

I already have the AWSSDK reference in the References.

I have also used Package Manager Console and tried uninstalling and installing AWSSDK but doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been resolved. It seems that the Class AmazonS3 which used to be inside Amazon namespace, has been moved to Amazon.S3 namespace. Just make sure to run the following commands using NuGet Package Manager.

uninstall-package AWSSDK
install-package AWSSDK

Once this is done, change the namespace from AmazonS3 to Amazon.S3.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Copy-Local = True for the AWSSDK assembly. This way when you create a release package / bundle to deploy in the Release mode the AWSSDK would also be part of the release bundle.

To set the Copy Local property to True or False

1. In Solution Explorer, click the Show All Files button to display the References node.
2. Open the References node for the project.
3. Right-click a reference in the References list, and click Properties.
4. The properties associated with that reference appear in a list in the Properties window.
5. Select Copy Local from the left-hand column, and then click the arrow in the right-hand column to change the value to True or False.

Reference : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/t1zz5y8c(v=vs.100).aspx